# how to index mysql database if product name are same in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

how to index mysql database if product name are same in a column?

Is it not possible to index a MySql database, if the product names are same in the product table?

For eg.) Let's say, the table has 2-3 Product names as same like 1) Pack of Biscuits 2) Pack of Biscuits 3) Pack of Biscuits. However, the IDs are different 1) 23 2) 26 3) 29

Is indexing not possible in this case?

Quick help will be appreciated. I am really stuck on this.

Regards
Amit

Comment: Indexes are on columns, so I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: You can index that col, but it wont do you a lot of good

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do and why also why you think this is a problem

Comment: Did you try to add the index and it failed? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: I suppose you still don't have any `index` column yet, simply create/add a new column for `id`, say with type `int` with `primary key` to identify unique rows. This way, you can have multiples of same **product name** with different **id**.

Answer (score 0):

The table with column `product_name` can have `INDEX(product_name)`.  That is a "non-unique" index; `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY` are "unique".

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE product_name = 'Pack of Biscuits';
```

will return 3 rows.  And it will (potentially) use that `INDEX`.